# Appcelerator app Timers for checking server api response

Tags: javascript, android, ios, timer, appcelerator

I am developing Appcelerator Titanium Alloy mobile app for Android and iOS. I have a user case where a certain action is performed by other app user which trigger change of object state on server. App is connected with REST api. Then other users should be notified by this change and their app should sync and update app state.

I believed I should be using timers to continuously check the api which inform other users that change has happen on server for state. Once this change is update I shall remove timers...

Is this good approach to use Timers?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

No timers. Should use sockets. I.e. when a change is made on the server, send a message via a web socket to all other users...

If you use timers you will always have to check because you're client will never know when a change happened... And you will waste many trips to the server asking 'anything new?' you can never remove your timer because you don't know when something changed.

Comment: thanks for your message... any reference can you also mention is using sockets in Appcelerator app?? or a particular library or server side set up??

Comment: There are some modules available here you could try out http://gitt.io/search?q=socket. The company I work for built our own implementation...

Comment: this is very helpful response. but i need to know more in reference to server side code. I am running PHP/MySql with rest services. Do I have to set up socket server on PHP side as well. Kindly guide a bit more.

Comment: My app scenario is A type of app user send invite to B type of user to accept invite. B type of user will accept invite and when he accept the invite I need to automatically show into A type of user app UI that B user has accepted invite. A user send invite request to B user with REST HTTP_POST from app. Rest API is implemented in PHP code on server. How in app for A user will I listen for socket based response ?

Comment: A socket server is on your server and socket client on the device. Once the connection is established,you can broadcast a message from the server the client or multiple clients. So User A sends invite to user B.. Now user B accepts the invite and that sends a socket message to the server, that message can now relay data via sockets to the device client A is connected to. So, immediately, Client A knows client B accepted the invite. This is the way most 'CHAT' type apps work. Polling may work (ie. your check the server every x minutes) if you don't need to know immediately.

Comment: Maybe something like this for PHP? http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html

Comment: So, in titanium app do I also have to use socket to make calls to my REST API? Totally new to sockets actually. Understood how php server side socket can be implemented.

Comment: Two choices, your socket could 'send' the data that has changed along with the message or it could just send a message that says 'something has changed', then you use your REST API to get the new changes. That is the way we do it. The socket just says, 'hey, something changed', then we make an API call to get the changed data. Reason we do that is because we have import functions that could add dozens of new records and so we monitor the socket. If there are a bunch of messages 'something new, 100 times in a row', then we wait until we stop getting messages and make one API call to get all.